# Regex all the characters in between each /. / could be zero to many

Tags: c#, regex

Im having a bit of trouble with this regex.  I have a line that could look like this

```
PREF-FA/WV/WB/LO...could continue
or
PREF-FA
```

and I need to grab all the ratings(FA/WV/WB etc) for each line, and put them in their own class.  Is this something regex could handle? or should I just split the string up?

I have a class called rating, and a List which length determines how many ratings are in that above line.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Regex
    .Matches("PREF-FA/WV/WB/LO" , @".+?-(?<rating>.{2})(?:/(?<rating>.{2}))*")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups["rating"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value))
```

gives an `IEnumerable<string>` with values "FA", "WV", "WB", "LO"

To go back to .Net2.0 world:

```
MatchCollection matches=Regex
    .Matches("PREF-FA/WV/WB/LO",@".+?-(?<rating>.{2})(?:/(?<rating>.{2}))*");

List<string> ratings=new List<string>();

foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    CaptureCollection captures=m.Groups["rating"].Captures;
    foreach(Capture c in captures)
    {
        ratings.Add(c.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow I would love this, but I am using .NET 2.0 and not 3.0 or above :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex `(?<=PREF-).*$`

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, "(?<=PREF-).*$", 
                          RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
```

It uses positive look behind to match `PREF-` and then mathces the succeeding string.
If you want to loop through all the mathces

```
Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=PREF-).*$",  RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match ItemMatch in ItemRegex.Matches(subjectString))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ItemMatch);
}
```

Comment: and then split the string? I need to get each rating into it's own class

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
((?:\w{2}/)*\w{2})$
```

`?:` to avoid capturing the 2-letter words and the slash.
Test it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) if you want. The regex works with many regex engines.

If the line always begins with `PREF-`, you could use:

```
^PREF-((?:\w{2}/)*\w{2})$
```